# Where is background artifact on UIImagePickerViewController?

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I have this black background displayed on the cells in my UIImagePickerController

[image: UIImagePickerController]

Here's how I'm presenting. No rocket science here:

```
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view;

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Obviously I just want the white background.....?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this app was using the Appearance Manager and had globally set all UITableViewCells to black like this:

`UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .blackColor()`